# Javascript: Resize div automatically when resize browser width

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to resize a div automatically when I resize the browser width. How can I do that?

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: If you apply a percentage width to your div it will resize automatically with the browser width, assuming the div is not inside a parent with a fixed width.

Answer (score 3):

using jQuery you can do

```
 window.onresize = function() {
     $("#fullWidthDiv").width($(window).width());
     $("#halfWidthDiv").width($(window).width()/2);
 }
```

or just use CSS and percent:

```
 <style> #fullWidthDiv{ width: 100% }
         #halfWidthDiv{ width: 50%  }
 </style>
```